# how to make the flutter border width expends outside not inside?

Tags: flutter

I'm a UX designer and need to know something about flutter to make sure that my design is feasible,

my question is, can I make an empty shape and just give it a border that can spread to outside from its shape the more I increase its width ?

and I need inside the shape to be empty so that user can interact with it and the border to be a frame ?

I tried to search for the answer on google but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible, by using the `Stack` (doc [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)) and `Positioned` (doc [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)) widgets.

By ordering the children widgets inside the `Stack` as needed and using the `fill` method of `Positioned` class, you should reach your UX objectives.